# ical parsing reoccuring events in python

Tags: python-3.x, icalendar

I am extremely new to python and icalendar but I am trying to grab my icalendar from Apple's Icloud website and then be able to access the calendar information so that I can display it on an app. I am able to get any event from the calendar that isn't reoccurring, but it only gets those events and for some reason skips over the reoccurring ones (which is basically the only type of events I schedule now of days) This is the code that I currently have, any ideas on how to get reoccurring events?

```
from icalendar import Calendar, Event
import urllib.request

def getCalendar():
    urlHome = urllib.request.urlopen('https://p10-calendarws.icloud.com/ca/subscribe/1/XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX').read()

    return urlHome

def displayCalendar(calendar):

    showCalHome = Calendar.from_ical(calHome)
    for event in showCalHome.walk('VEVENT'):
        date = event.get('dtstart').dt
        summary = event.get('summary')
        print(summary,date)


calendar = getCalendar()
displayCalendar(calendar)
```

Any thoughts or ideas on what I can do to not only get a list of single events, but also reoccurring events?

Comment: I guess one of the main issues I'm having is that it doesn't recognize reoccurring events as events that are happening today rather as past events that repeat, maybe that helps with trying to find the solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured it out by parsing through the ICS file itself, turning alot of values into strings and then comparing the strings to what I was looking for, looked something like this:

```
import json
import requests
from icalendar import Calendar, Event
import urllib.request
from datetime import *
import datetime
from dateutil.rrule import *


def getCalendar():
    urlWork = urllib.request.urlopen('https://p10-calendarws.icloud.com/ca/subscribe/1/XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX').read()
    urlHome = urllib.request.urlopen('https://p10-calendarws.icloud.com/ca/subscribe/1/XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX').read()

    calendars = [urlHome, urlWork]

    return calendars

def getTodaysEvents(calendars):

    calHome = calendars[0]
    calWork = calendars[1]

    allEvents = []
    singleEvents = {}
    homeEvents = {}
    workEvents = {}

    today = str(date.today())
    year = today[0:4]
    month = today[5:7]
    day = today[8:10]
    currentDay = year + month + day

    showCalHome = Calendar.from_ical(calHome)
    for component in showCalHome.walk():
        if component.name == "VEVENT":
            rule = component.get('rrule')
            eventDay = str(component.get('dtstart').dt)
            if rule is not None:
                rrule = dict(rule)
                if 'UNTIL' in rrule.keys():
                    eventEnd = str(rrule['UNTIL'][0])
                    eventEndYear = eventEnd[0:4]
                    eventEndMonth = eventEnd[5:7]
                    eventEndDay = eventEnd[8:10]
                    endEvent = eventEndYear + eventEndMonth + eventEndDay
                    if int(endEvent) >= int(currentDay):
                        print(component.get('summary'))
                        homeEvents['CALENDAR'] = "HOME"
                        homeEvents['SUMMARY'] = (component.get('summary'))
                        homeEvents['LOCATION'] = (component.get('location'))
                        homeEvents['START'] = (component.get('dtstart').dt)
                        homeEvents['END'] = (component.get('dtend').dt)
                        allEvents.append(homeEvents)
                # else: (NEED TO IMPLEMENT WEEKLY EVENTS THAT DON'T END and Events that aren't Reoccuring)
                #    print(component.get('summary'))
                #    if component.get('location') != 'None':
                #        print(component.get('location'))
                #    print(component.get('dtstart').dt)
                #    print(component.get('dtend').dt)
            else:
                if str(date.today()) == eventDay[0:10]:
                    print(component.get('summary'))
                    singleEvents['CALENDAR'] = "HOME"
                    singleEvents['SUMMARY'] = (component.get('summary'))
                    singleEvents['LOCATION'] = (component.get('location'))
                    singleEvents['START'] = (component.get('dtstart').dt)
                    singleEvents['END'] = (component.get('dtend').dt)
                    allEvents.append(singleEvents)
            print(allEvents)


    showCalWork = Calendar.from_ical(calWork)
    for component in showCalWork.walk():
        if component.name == "VEVENT":
            rule = component.get('rrule')
            if rule is not None:
                rrule = dict(rule)
                today = str(date.today())
                year = today[0:4]
                month = today[5:7]
                day = today[8:10]
                currentDay = year + month + day
                if 'UNTIL' in rrule.keys():
                    eventEnd = str(rrule['UNTIL'][0])
                    eventEndYear = eventEnd[0:4]
                    eventEndMonth = eventEnd[5:7]
                    eventEndDay = eventEnd[8:10]
                    endEvent = eventEndYear + eventEndMonth + eventEndDay
                    if int(endEvent) >= int(currentDay):
                        workEvents['CALENDAR'] = "WORK"
                        workEvents['SUMMARY'] = (component.get('summary'))
                        workEvents['LOCATION'] = (component.get('location'))
                        workEvents['START'] = (component.get('dtstart').dt)
                        workEvents['END'] = (component.get('dtend').dt)
                        allEvents.append(workEvents)
                # else:
                #    print(component.get('summary'))
                #    if component.get('location') != 'None':
                #        print(component.get('location'))
                #    print(component.get('dtstart').dt)
                #    print(component.get('dtend').dt)

    return allEvents


def displayEvents(events):
    print(events)
    print()
    print("TODAY:")
    for event in range(len(events)):
        start = str(events[event]['START'])[11:16]
        end = str(events[event]["END"])[11:16]
        if int(start[0:2]) < 12:
            sT = "AM"
        else:
            pmtime = int(start[0:2]) - 12
            start[0:2].replace(start[0:2], str(pmtime))
            sT = "PM"
        if int(end[0:2]) < 12:
            eT = "AM"
        else:
            pmtime = int(end[0:2]) - 12
            end = str(pmtime) + end[2:5]
            eT = "PM"

        print(events[event]['SUMMARY'] + " - " + events[event]["CALENDAR"])
        if str(events[event]['LOCATION']) != "None":
            print(events[event]['LOCATION'])
        if start[0] == "0" and end[0] == "0":
            print(start[1:5] + sT + " - " + end[1:5] + eT)
        elif start[0] == "0":
            print(start[1:5] + sT + " - " + end + eT)
        elif end[0] == "0":
            print(start + sT + " - " + end[1:5] + eT)
        else:
            print(start + sT + " - " + end + eT)

calendars = getCalendar()
events = getTodaysEvents(calendars)
displayEvents(events)
```

Answer (score 0):

I created a [library](https://pypi.org/project/recurring-ical-events/) because I was looking for the exact same use-case.

In your case, `recurring-ical-events` could be embedded like this:

```
events = recurring_ical_events.of(calendar).between(start_date, end_date)
for event in events:
    # ...
```